# Compare two Columns using index position

Tags: r, dataframe, data-analysis, data-cleaning

[image: The dataframe]

I have a scenario where I have to compare two columns in a dataframe. The condition is that the Field1 column has a set of values. Field2 column has few values and the remaining are NA. There is another column called Field3. So, the work here is to compare the Field1 values with Field2. The conditions to compare are as follows.

1. If Field1 has a corresponding row in Field2. Copy the row value of Field2.
   Ex. Location and Place. So, I have to copy Place.
2. If Field1 does not have a corresponding Field2 value. Then compare Field1 
   with Field3. Copy the Field3 value to Field2.

Kindly suggest a way to go about this.

```
dft <- data.frame(Field1 = c("Location","Time","Date","Problem"), 
          Field2 = c("Place","Balance","NA","NA"),
          Field3 = c("NA","NA","Pay","NA"))
```

Comment: Can we see any effort from your part to solving this? Also what happens if Field 1 does not have neither Field2 nor Field3?

Comment: Field will have a value always matching either Field2 or Field3

Comment: In your example, row 4 does not. Please be explicit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the problem correctly, you are trying to replace `NA`s in `Field2` with values from `Field3`, and replace `NA`s in `Field3` with values from `Field2`. Assuming there is always one `NA` and one string in either `Field2` or `Field3` for each observation, you can use dplyr's `coalesce` to combine them:

```r
library(dplyr)
mutate(df, Field4 = coalesce(Field2, Field3))

#### OUTPUT ####

    Field1  Field2 Field3  Field4
1 Location   Place   <NA>   Place
2     Time Balance   <NA> Balance
3     Date    <NA>    Pay     Pay
4  Problem    <NA>  Check   Check
```

Just make sure your `NA`s are really `NA`s not strings like `"NA"`. For example, compare the values in this dataframe with the dataframe you gave us. Also, make sure your variables contain strings and not factors:

```r
df <- data.frame(Field1 = c("Location","Time","Date","Problem"), 
                  Field2 = c("Place","Balance", NA, NA),
                  Field3 = c(NA, NA, "Pay","Check"), stringsAsFactors = F)
```

***Note***: I've replaced one `NA` to match the dataframe in the image, i.e. `c("NA","NA","Pay","NA")` is `c("NA","NA","Pay","Check")` in the above dataframe.

Comment: Very good idea! +1 for not going with the nested `ifelse` method

Comment: BTW I rolled the question back before your edit since changing that value changes the question. Such changes should only be done by OP despite how 'sure' we are. The best thing to do is to put a note in your answer

Comment: @Sotos okay makes sense. Thanks for the heads up. I've add a note to the bottom of my answer.